# I'm getting an lvalue error

Tags: c, system-calls, multiprocess

```
    main(){

     helloworld();
}
void helloworld(){
     cout<<"hellowowrld";
}
```

it outputs hello world, what wrong with it?

Comment: You forgot the `^M` after the last line.^M

Answer (score 5):

this line you are missing an =

```
 if(pipe(pfd2) =-1){
```